# Pulling down plugin from cordova plugin repository is very slow on one machine

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

On my Mac, pulling down a Cordova plugin through npm is excruciatingly slow, taking upwards of a minute:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

However, if I use the git URL then it is as quick as anything, taking around 5 seconds:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

This is repeatable any number of times, so I don't think it's to do with local caching.

Other npm commands seem to return normally, eg this takes about a second as well:

```
npm install lodash
```

Other people, also using a Mac on the same network, don't have this problem.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Cordova solved my issue.

`sudo npm install -g cordova`